# How to get the form of component from module?

Tags: component, module, jform, model

I tried to get a component form from my module. I got the model and then tried to get the form, but the result was empty. I tried to define 'JPATH_COMPONENT' and it was useless.

```
define('JPATH_COMPONENT', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_business');

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_business/models');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Organization', 'BusinessModel'); //It is correct

$form = $model ->get('Form'); //empty
print_r($form);
```

Comment: Don't use `JPATH_COMPONENT` **and** `JPATH_SITE`. You only need to use `JPATH_SITE`

Comment: The same question [was asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474214/joomla-3-2-get-form-component-from-module) before. I thought if I define the constatn in helps

Comment: Yes, you define the constant, but you need to use JPATH_SITE. JPATH_COMPONENT cannot be used outside the component, so seeing as you're using a module, it won't work ;)

Comment: JPATH_COMPONENT points to the currently component path. Now if you're in a module that may be used on other component pages - so not only will it not really help - but by defining the constant there you might screw up components who are relying that constant to be the component currently being viewed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add an additional path where to look for forms before your call to `$model->get('Form')`.

```
JForm::addFormPath(YOUR_COMPONENT_FORMS_PATH);
```

You will need it because getForm calls loadForm (declared on the ancestor class JModelForm) which, before getting the form instance, uses this

```
JForm::addFormPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/forms');
JForm::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');
```

Alternatively you may use `JForm::getInstance` to get an instance of your form.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have some issues 
`JForm::addFormPath('/components/com_business/models/forms');
JForm::addFieldPath('/administrator/components/com_business/models/fields');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_business/models');

$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Organization', 'BusinessModel');

$form = $model ->getForm();

print_r($form); //empty`

Comment: `JForm::addFormPath('/components/com_business/models/forms');
JForm::addFieldPath('/administrator/components/com_business/models/fields');

$form = JForm::getInstance('Organization'); //throws error "0 JForm::getInstance(name, *string*)"`

Comment: This method works, but I think it's not good way

`$form = new JForm('organization');
$form ->loadFile(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_business/models/forms/organization.xml');
print_r($form); //correct`

Comment: I forgot to set JPATH_SITE in JForm::addFormPath, now it is works, Sorry :)

Comment: Nice to help you :)